# Xcode 6.x Story board button size issues

Tags: ios, ios8, uibutton, xcode6, xcode-storyboard

We have added image sets to the xcassets folder.  They are all named properly.  When we set up a button with constraints the box for the image scales, but the image itself stays the same size on all phones... how do you set it up to keep the button image scaling to the relative size so the proportion stays the same on all screen sizes and the 1x 2x 3x images are utilized.

See screen shot here (sorry still dont have enough points to post photos so here are links)

https://www.evernote.com/l/AHGB5KrFQCtHtJAV1u5AP1eG_G1KpeMznXg

this has the proper 1x, 2x, and 3x images

Here is what it looks like in preview for the various phone sizes, notice the buttons (images of male and female do not scale).

Xcode Preview option

https://www.evernote.com/l/AHGq50vKq3tG151kfmUG4mjK0Iz6yYeg_Ck

So not 100% sure what the issue is or if this is just an issue with buttons and xcode not properly scaling based upon the 1x,2, and 3x..

any thoughts?

Comment: Here is what the constraints look like in the storyboard.. https://www.evernote.com/l/AHEeFeEgN4RDlpC8YQdCjnAmFZrlzo5d788